# Skipping Exception in ItemProcessor leads to quadratic behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is there a way to change the skipping behavior of the ItemProcessor, to behave like the ItemWriter? Throwing a skipable exception in the ItemProcessor results in reprocessing of all already accepted items, leading to a behavior which is quadratic in its complexity. Is there a way to change the behavior to do a rollback on all Items and process the elements one by one, just like the ItemWriter?

Job definition:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(step(null)).build();
}

@Bean
public Step step(ReaderProcessorWriter readerProcessorWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<Integer, Integer>chunk(20).faultTolerant()
            .skip(RuntimeException.class).skipLimit(10)
            .reader(readerProcessorWriter)
            .processor(readerProcessorWriter)
            .writer(readerProcessorWriter)
            .build();
}
```

Reader, Processor and Writer:

```
@Component
public static class ReaderProcessorWriter extends ListItemReader<Integer> implements ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer>, ItemWriter<Integer> {
    private int run;

    public ReaderProcessorWriter() {
        super(List.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8 ,9));
    }

    @Override
    public Integer process(Integer integer) {
        // Probably some long computation involving lots of DB Reading, lasting minutes at worst
        if (integer >= 5) {
            System.out.println("FAIL: " + integer);
            throw new RuntimeException("Hue hue");
        }
        System.out.println("OK: " + integer);
        return integer;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Integer> list) {
        if (run++ == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Writer");
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OK: 0
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
OK: 4
FAIL: 5
OK: 0
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
OK: 4
FAIL: 6
OK: 0
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
OK: 4
FAIL: 7
OK: 0
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
OK: 4
FAIL: 8
OK: 0
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
OK: 4
FAIL: 9
OK: 0
OK: 1
OK: 2
OK: 3
OK: 4
OK: 0
[0]
OK: 1
[1]
OK: 2
[2]
OK: 3
[3]
OK: 4
[4]
```

In the example the Items 0-4 are processed 6 times before they are successfully written (assuming the Writer would not throw).

- 5 Times because of the rollbacks on the processor
- 1 for the successful processing

If the ItemProcessor used the same skipping strategy as the ItemWriter, then they would be processed only 2 times:

- 1 time for failure in Processing
- 1 time in separate transactions

Comment: maybe use RetryTemplate?

Comment: maybe use RetryTemplate?
see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: Retry templates work only with transient exceptions like Network failure, concurrent modification or optimistic locking. If the exception is caused by malformed data, then the RetryTemplate leads to Step Failure instead of Skipping the element.

Comment: I meant use it to manage some external state object in case of an exception and use  that object as a watermark to resume processing from? I couldn’t find anything else on the internet, maybe because batch processing isn’t meant to resume in case of failure, I think you will have to implement a workaround

Comment: Yes it does. That's the reason for the Skip mechanism. There is a simple solution - just move all the business logic to the ItemWriter, but it's not the cleanest approach. The approach with the internal object fails, because the transaction has been rolled back and the write did never occur and it messes with restartability.

Comment: I haven’t worked with spring batch, but moving business logic from itemprocessor to itemwriter still seems like a work around.

Comment: Yes write will never have occurred, in that case the internal object will have to contain high watermark along with previous processed items. Yes it’s not clean. Stack overflow contains similar questions from a while back, they don’t have any answers either

Comment: The mechanisms that the object would achieve are already a part of Spring Batch. It would be a far worse workaround, because it would mean that the items are stored between transactions, which would create more issues than it solves. The solution with business logic in the ItemWriter would work just and would still be inside of the transaction boundaries. Id would split the execution after a failure and retry all write operations in separate transactions and skip the ones which cause the failure.

Comment: Another workaround which works just fine would be just returning an object which holds the Result or the Exception and throwing it in the ItemWriter when present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231581/discussion-between-zeeshan-arif-and-adrian-jaloszewski).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to configure the fault tolerant processor to be non-transactional. It will then cache the processing result of the successful processed items such that in case of the rollback and during the retry of processing the chunk again , it just get the processing result from the cache instead of reprocessing the successful item again.

```java
@Bean
public Step step(ReaderProcessorWriter readerProcessorWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<Integer, Integer>chunk(20).faultTolerant()
            .skip(RuntimeException.class).skipLimit(10)
            .reader(readerProcessorWriter)
            .processor(readerProcessorWriter)
            .processorNonTransactional()
            .writer(readerProcessorWriter)
            .build();
}
```

You have to see if it is okay for your use case. When using JPA for processing the items , I feel more safe that in case of the rollback , all entities that are loaded and processed in the rollbacked transaction should be discarded and better not reuse them in another new transaction as the entities will become detached in the new transaction which seems to make things more complicated to me.

If reprocessing of an item takes a considerable amount of time , I will try to see if the bottleneck operation within processing an item can be fine tune such as using cache to cache result of those expansive operations.

Comment: I also feel much safer when  all entities are discarded on rollback, but I'm looking for a way to use the same skip behavior as the ItemWriter has - on skip all entities are discarded and every single one of them is reprocessed in a separate transaction.

Comment: I think you can try to customize the `completionPolicy` ( or even a new `chunkOperations` ?) when using the builder to build the step such that in case of skipping happens , it will change the `chunkSize` to 1. Something similar to the existing `SimpleCompletionPolicy` but its size will be updated to 1 if skipping happens. You can see if the  `RepeatListener` would be helpful to let you receive the event in case of skipping happens such that you can update the `chunkSize`.

Comment: but as one of the key point to have high performance batch job is try to batch several items to process and commit in a transaction.So making each transaction only processes only one item will slow down your batch job. I still would go for the options to make processing of each item to be very fast (e.g using cache etc.) such that even though spring-batch will re-process the items in such case , its impact due to this reprocessing is  very much negligible when compared to the performance gain when batching several items to be commit/written in the same transaction.

Comment: Yes, but it is still faster than redoing the transaction for all the elements except for the failing one. When you have 100 elements and the last three are malformed, then the processing of the first 97 will happen 4 times (almost 400 calls to process, compared to just 200). When the last 10 fail, then you have ~800 calls to process, compared to 200, when the last 20 fail, you have ~1700 calls to process instead of 200.

Comment: well you have to measure it.. May be you are right , but I am talking about in case of the reprocessing an item , it is fine tuning to the level just like calling a local java method without connecting to any external system (i.e single digit of ms if it is possible) and based on my experience and taken your last example,  process 80 items in 80 transactions (i.e 1 item per transaction) + 200 `process()` call VS process 80 items in 1 transactions + 1700 `process()` calls. Then latter is still much faster . But it is for my case , you have to measure it for your use case.

Comment: No, in the case of the skippable exception in the ItemProcessor it's around 21 transactions, of which every one has to process 80-81 elements. The 1700 process calls are evenly distributed among the 21 transactions. 

Worst case is when half of the items have errors, then it's ~2500 calls in 50 transactions.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this issue are the following wrappers, which postpone the thrown Exception until the ItemWriter, which splits the failed chunk in single transactions. I still wonder whether there is a standard Spring Batch solution for this issue:

```
public static class Either<T> {
    private final T t;
    private final Exception e;

    public Either(T t, Exception e) {
        this.t = t;
        this.e = e;
    }

    public T get() throws Exception {
        if (e != null) {
            throw e;
        }
        return t;
    }
}

public static class EitherItemProcessor<Input, Output> implements ItemProcessor<Input, Either<Output>> {
    private final ItemProcessor<Input, Output> wrapped;

    public EitherItemProcessor(ItemProcessor<Input, Output> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Either<Output> process(Input input) throws Exception {
        try {
            return new Either<>(wrapped.process(input), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Either<>(null, e);
        }
    }
}


public static class EitherItemWriter<Output> implements ItemWriter<Either<Output>> {
    private final ItemWriter<Output> itemWriter;

    public EitherItemWriter(ItemWriter<Output> itemWriter) {
        this.itemWriter = itemWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Either<Output>> list) throws Exception {
        List<Output> outputs = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        for (Either<Output> e : list) {
            outputs.add(e.get());
        }
        itemWriter.write(outputs);
    }
}
```